# Identify that the logged in user is an administrator or not using velocity

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I would like to identify that the logged in user is an administrator or not using velocity. The goal is to show the dockbar to the administrator user(s) only.

I have tried following code, but is not working for me:

```
#if ($is_signed_in && $permissionChecker.isGroupAdmin($group_id))
    #dockbar()
#end
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Do you want to show dockbar to all the admin type users or just to specific admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the requirement, there are following two ways to check whether the logged in user is an admin user or not:

**Show dockbar to all the admin users:**

```
#if ($is_signed_in && $permissionChecker.isOmniadmin())
    #dockbar()
#end
```

**Show dockbar to specific admin user(s) based on role-name:**

```
#set($showDockBar = false)
#foreach($role in $$themeDisplay.getUser().getRoles())
    #if ($role.Name == 'Administrator' || $role.Name == 'Web Administrator')
        #set($showDockBar = true)
    #end
#end

#if ($is_signed_in && $showDockBar)
    #dockbar()
#end
```